# Is there non conductive solder?

Tags: soldering, induction-motor, electric-machine

I am making a project in my university and I really need to find a way to glue back together two blocks of the stator (part of an electric motor).

As you probably know the sator is composed of sheets of metal that are glued together, well, during manufacture some of these sheets came loose. Entire sheet, the stator became separated in the middle, so we kinda have 300 sheets in each separated portion. Some of my colleagues mentioned soldering the outside of the sheets together and thus glueing the thing back together.

What we did for the manufacture (before the sheet blocks came loose) was build a jig that compressed the metal sheets and the whole thing went into the oven. The thing we are trying to avoid is going through that whole process again since it is very costly and takes weeks to send to the manufacturer.

edit: I'm a second year student, so yeah, young blood here!

[image: image link: https://ibb.co/Svw58mN]

Comment: That's called glue.

Comment: [You can "weld" plastics.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Plastic_welding), that what you mean?

Comment: "**_Solder is a fusible metal alloy used to create a permanent bond between metal workpieces_**"

Comment: Epoxy..........

Comment: Color me curious!  What are you soldering on the stator?

Comment: Smells like an X-Y problem to me ... Do you really need to "solder a stator" with "non conductive solder"? *Really*? What are you actually trying to achieve - there may be a much better way to get where you're trying to go if you just give us some more detail...

Comment: im new at this so sorry if I know close to little about these topics. As you probably know the sator is composed of sheets of metal that are glued together, well, during manufacture some of these sheets came loose, and I was looking for a quick fix :)

Comment: How much of the sheet? Just a frayed edge? Or the entire sheet?

Comment: Entire sheet, the stator became separated in the middle, so we kinda have 300 sheets in each separated portion. Some of my colleagues mentioned soldering the outside of the sheets together and thus glueing the thing back together

Comment: Ugh. Yeah epoxy. Maybe even single component heat cured stuff. And maybe a vacuum press or at least fixtures and weights to hold it. No solder. Make sure you have a way to line it up.

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into that

Comment: Well you probably can't use a vacuum press AND an oven at the sane time. That would be an autoclave which you do not have most likely.

Comment: what we did the first time (before the sheet blocks came loose) was build a jig that compressed the metal sheets and the whole thing went into the oven. The thing we are trying to avoid is going through that whole process again since it is very costly and takes weeks to send to the manufacturer.

Comment: You should add some of your specific comments to the question for someone in the future because many of us ignore a bank of comments.

Comment: A stator is stationary.  A rotor rotates.  If that is the stator, it's pretty weird looking and there are no wires!

Comment: I was not clear when I mentioned stator, this whole block will then be cut to make both things, thats why there is also no wires or anything implemented!

Comment: Before you try epoxy, make sure that your surfaces are pristine -- lightly sand with fine grit, steel wool, clean with soap, then clean with acid (vinegar?), completely dry, then finally glue with epoxy.

Comment: If you're going to be "cutting the whole block" then you might be able to put weld-stripes down the sides, on some material to be later cut out, to hold everything together while you machine it.

Comment: Let me know if you have any questions about my other comments.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Solder is, by definition, a metal alloy, and all metals are conductive.

Epoxies are good at fixing things together in a similar way, and are non-conductive to electricity, and much more poorly conducting to heat than metals.

Comment: Thank you so much! I posted on other places and everyone is pointing me to epoxies :)
But do you know any epoxy that is good for this sort of application?

Comment: @JoãoLoureiro You did not actually describe your application.

Comment: @DKNguyen just explained in the discussion above, thanks!

Comment: @JoãoLoureiro, the details belong in the question, not in the comments. Your photo just shows two black cylinders. I can't see what you're trying to fix.

Answer (score 0):

If that's a stator, where are the slots? Where does the rotor go?
Methinks that is the ROTOR, and I have never heard of the laminations of a rotor (or stator for that matter) held together by glue or epoxy, they are either welded or bolted. this entire question seems made up.